How to solve the issue of increasing the cost function instead of decreasing it
I have a sample complex Neural Network with one layer that act as the following:
First, I have a well-known complex matrix with size N x N, I extracted the 1:4:N columns from that matrix to have the matrix V of size N x N/4, I want to multiply the matrix V with a a well-known vector s that contains 1 and -1 with size N/4 x 1 such that y = Vs, where y will be of size N x 1. So I want the last N/4 elements of the vector y to be zeros or near to zeros. So, I first inserted the vector s into the neural network before multiplying it with V matrix. Then, the training is performed to find the best weights of the neural layer that optimize the last N/4 elements of the vector y.
The problem I found is that the cost function is increasing during the training instead of the decreasing, also the result after the training is the vector y = VGs doesn't not contain zeros or near-to-zeros values in its last N/4 elements, G here represents the weights the neural network after the training.
Here is the code I wrote:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

# Parameters
N = 64

class ComplexNormal(tf.keras.initializers.Initializer):    #to build the complex NN
    """Complex normal initializer."""
    def __call__(self, shape, dtype=None):
        real_part = tf.random.normal(shape, stddev=0.5)
        imag_part = tf.random.normal(shape, stddev=0.5)
        return tf.dtypes.complex(real_part, imag_part)

#Generate the vector s
s_vector = tf.random.uniform(shape=(N//4,1), minval=0, maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32)
s_vector = tf.where(s_vector == 0, -1, 1)  # Convert 0 to -1 and 1 stays 1
s_vector = tf.cast(s_vector, dtype=tf.complex64)

def Matrix_multiplication(x, N):
    Vector_pilot = tf.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=tf.complex64)
    n = tf.range(N, dtype=tf.float32)
    k = tf.reshape(n, (N, 1))

    imaginary_part = 2 * np.pi * n * k / tf.cast(N, tf.float32)  # Imaginary part for the V matrix
    omega = tf.exp(tf.complex(0.0, imaginary_part))  # Complex exponential the matrix
    Matrix_V = omega / tf.sqrt(tf.cast(N, tf.complex64))  # Normalize the  matrix
    pilot_ind = tf.range(0, N, delta=4, dtype=tf.int32) # Create pilot_ind array equivalent to [1:4:N] in MATLAB

    V_matrix_selected = tf.gather(Matrix_V, pilot_ind, axis=1)  # Extract columns 1:4:end
    y_vector = tf.matmul(V_matrix_selected, Vector_pilot)
    return y_vector

# Use the subcarrier into the model
input_data = Input(shape=(N//4,), dtype=tf.complex64)
layer_1 = Dense(N//4, activation='linear', kernel_initializer=ComplexNormal(), dtype=tf.complex64)(input_data)  # The first layer

y2 = Matrix_multiplication(tf.transpose(layer_1), N)    # Multiply the output with the maxtrix V

model = Model(inputs=input_data, outputs=layer_1)

UW = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(y2[-N//4:, :]))  #Reduce the mean of the last N/4 elements of vector y2
model.add_loss(UW)

s_vector_repeated = tf.tile(tf.transpose(s_vector), [5000000,1])  #Generate the data with 5000000 training size
data = tf.convert_to_tensor(s_vector_repeated, dtype=tf.complex64)

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001))
model.fit(data, epochs=200, steps_per_epoch=1000, verbose=2)

